# Writing a unix script

Tags: javascript, unix, browser

I don't know much about unix, but I could really use some direction. Here's what I'd like to do:

- Change my IP address (I imagine via a proxy list or something?)
- Connect to a web page, and then run some javascript
- Change IP again, and run script on page again.

Is this doable, and where should I go to get this ball rolling? I need to get this script running by tonight.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which IP address (client or server) do you want to change, and why?

Comment: Look at `ifconfig` for changing your IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using the two strategies below:

1. You typically change the IP address of a UNIX machine using a utility such as [ifconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig).
2. Web pages can be programmatically retrieved using utilities such as [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) and [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) but programmatically executing browser-based JavaScript is a different beast altogether - solutions exist but they seem to be "researchy" as of yet.  You might have more luck executing JavaScript hosted on a website by driving Firefox (or another browser) via its automation tool, if one exists (e.g. by a plugin, or a testing tool such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)).

Good luck getting it tonight!